# Get Average GameCenter Leaderboard Score?

Tags: game-center

1) So I currently have a leaderboard that is based on people's score. Their scores are doubles, 0.00 - 100.00.

So if there are only 2 people on the leaderboard, one with a score of 90.00 and the other with a score of 80.00, i want to be able to tally up all of the scores and divide by the number of people on the leaderboard... in this case 90.00 + 80.00 / 2.0

So does anyone know how to do this?

2) Second, I want to create a leaderboard that the user can see their ranking, but is unable to see other people's names. Is there a way to do that as well? I know I could make a custom interface that only shows their ranking, but then if they open the gamecenter app, they would be able to look up my app and see names and rankings but I don't want to allow that.

3) Is there a way to make a leaderboard only show the user's most recent submission? For instance, if their first submit a 70.0, then a 80.0, then a 60.0, then a 71.2, it will only show the 71.2?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:
1. This is not possible with standard GameKit API. You will need your own server to achieve this.
2. You are right, even if you create a custom UI for leaderboards, the user will be able to see other players scores in the game center app. But if you just want local player highscore, store it locally and use iCloud to synchronise it.
3. This is also impossible with GameKit. But if you store it locally, you can do it your way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Game Center doesn't provide API for fetching an average score. If you could fetch all the scores on the leaderboard, you could easily use [KVC collection operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) to compute their average. However, you can't get all the scores on a leaderboard -- its [`range`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009584-CH1-SW3) property only allows you to fetch up to 100 scores.
2. Any leaderboards you create using Game Center will be visible in the Game Center app, names and all. (Note that only nicknames are shown for people not in your friends list -- if your question has to do with privacy of real names, you needn't be concerned.)
3. You can now use iTunes Connect to control whether a leaderboard shows each player's highest score or their most recently submitted score -- see under "score submission type" in [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/15_GameCenter/GameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH7-SW15).